# Unzipping file Zip Exception: invalid entry size (expected 193144 but got 193138 bytes)

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file (retrieved from an FTP server):

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    while (ze != null) {
        String fileName = ze.getName();
        File newFile = new File(outputFileName+outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);
        System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        fos.close();
        sendFile = newFile;
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }
    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
```

I have only one text file in the .zip file. This code works fine on my local windows machine. However, when deployed onto ubuntu server, it throws the following exception..

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 193144 but got 193138 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:386)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:156)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
```

at com.empress.Xsync.updater.ClientConfiguration.unZipFile(ClientConfiguration.java:246)

I have manually unzipped it..works fine.
Original .txt file size is 193144 bytes.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the problem, but `InputStream.read(...)` returns `-1` at EOF and can return `0` without there being an error, so you should check for `>= 0` or `!= -1`, not `> 0`.

Comment: Tried that too.. Did not solve the problem!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like your zip file has been corrupted in the process of transferring it to the Ubuntu machine.  Try unzipping the same file from the command line on the Ubuntu machine to see if it also reports problems.

If I was to make a random guess, it would be that you transferred the ZIP file via FTP and used 'ascii' mode instead of 'binary' mode.  (FTP could have converted `'\r\n'` to `'\n'` six times ...)